# WPF Smith HTML editor is changing all my HTML tags to upper case

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I'm building WPF application that's using the Smith HTML Editor. The application is MVVM and I've got the Smith control bound to a field with HTML content. Everything is working ok, except that the IsDirty implementation that I'm working on gets triggered if you click in or even mouse over the HTML control. I looked a little closer and found that as soon as the control looses focus it changes all my tags to upper case (thus the app sees the field as changed and sets the model to dirty.)

I'm having a hard time putting my hands on any documentation for this control, but so far I haven't been able to find anywhere to control this behaviour.

Here's the XAML for the control:

```
<smith:HtmlEditor Name="fldcomments" Height="320" BindingContent="{Binding Path=Student.Comments, Mode=TwoWay }"/>
```

I'd appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0):

So this is kludgey as hell, but it's the best I came up with. I used [NUglify](https://github.com/xoofx/NUglify) to extract the plain text and added that as a comparison for my field setter function. Here's the code for the function:

```
protected void SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {

           if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                IsDirty = true;

            if ((propertyName == "Comments") && (value != null) && (field != null))
            {

                var ugField = Uglify.HtmlToText((value as string));
                var ugValue = Uglify.HtmlToText(field as string);
                string strField = Regex.Replace(ugField.Code, @"\s+", string.Empty);
                string strValue = Regex.Replace(ugValue.Code, @"\s+", string.Empty);

                if (strField == strValue)
                { IsDirty = false; }
            }

                field = value;

                OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            }

        }
```

I had to add the regex.replace to get rid of some extra whitespace that the HTMLToText function left in there.

I'm not proud, but it works. Still very open to a better solution.